# array_filter em array dentro de objeto SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
["cinema"]=>
  array(82) {
[0]=>
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (11) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "716"
    ["grupo-economico"]=>
    string(8) "Cinemark"
  }
  ["nome"]=>
  string(10) "Aricanduva"
  ["nome-amigavel"]=>
  string(10) "aricanduva"
  ["venda-internet"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["endereco"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#86 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["latitude"]=>
      string(9) "-23.56582"
      ["longitude"]=>
      string(9) "-46.50364"
    }
  }
  ["precos"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#87 (0) {
  }
...
```

Estou tentando acessar o `array` `["cinema"]` para usa-lo em `array_filter` porém ao acessa-lo recebo apenas `NULL`.

```
$xml->complexos // Retorna a estrutura acima
$xml->complexos["cinema"] // NULL
$xml->complexos->cinema // Retorna apenas o primeiro elemento do array
```

** Importante: Eu sei que funciona com `foreach` porém preciso usar o `array_filter` para deixar o código o mais simples e legível possível.

Comment: bom dia! Já tentou converter esse objeto em array?